# How to dynamically call different xsl file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have three working xsl files, now I simply want to make them work together.

Suppose my three xslt are `cham1.xsl, cham2.xsl, cham3.xsl` and my source input `source.xml`. In the top table node of the input, there is an attribute `outputclass`:

```
 <root outputclass="cham1">
```

What I want is how could I write another stylesheet, that whenever, the `@outputclass` is `cham1`, then call `cham1.xsl`, if `@outputclass='cham2'`, then apply `cham2.xsl` on the source.

Wonder if this is feasible in xslt? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can add a sample of your XSLTs. You should be able to create a 'container' XSLT which includes the 3 separate XSLTs, and then applies the appropriate set of templates based on your criteria.templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two approaches: doing this within XSLT (in a single transformation), or doing it externally.

To do it within XSLT, the best way would be to ensure that the template rules in cham1.xsl, cham2.xsl, and cham3.xsl use different modes. The controlling code then simply needs to do apply-templates in the appropriate mode.

Doing it outside XSLT rather depends on your application environment, e.g. whether you are controlling things from Java, from Ant, from XProc, or etc.